# RoR free element from array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have an element in a array such that,

```
[#<Name id: 23, first_name: "anderson", last_name: "gorge">]
```

how can i remove the array block, so that i want it as

```
#<Name id: 23, first_name: "anderson", last_name: "gorge">
```

without array block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean you have a *single* element in an array and you want to extract it? There so many ways of doing it, 2 that quickly come to mind are:

```
>> obj = [#<Name id: 23, first_name: "anderson", last_name: "gorge">].first
=> #<Name id: 23, first_name: "anderson", last_name: "gorge">
>> obj = [#<Name id: 23, first_name: "anderson", last_name: "gorge">].shift
=> #<Name id: 23, first_name: "anderson", last_name: "gorge">
```

Comment: If this isn't what you are looking for, then I am afraid you will have to be a bit more lucid with the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
irb(main):005:0> arr = ["#"]
irb(main):006:0> elem = arr.first
irb(main):008:0> elem == "#"
=> true
```